# "Create Field for Parameter" Intention in IntelliJ only applies to one parameter?

Tags: intellij-idea

How do I get the intention "Create Field for Parameter" in IntelliJ to apply to all the parameters in a call instead of having to press through the list of keypresses for each and every parameter?

I have lots of calls with 10+ parameters that I get tired of having to do one by one and it would really help to be able to just have IntelliJ create all of the fields for me directly.

Comment: @Hay's answer is correct, but it seems you need to make sure your cursor is on the constructor's identifier, e.g. `public MyClass(String a, String b) {` (tested with version 2018.1)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know this question is 7 years old, but I was looking for this and **Bind constructor parameters to fields** does that (press `Alt-Enter`, it is just above *Create field for Parameter*).

Comment: Make sure your cursor is on the constructor and not on any individual parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I fear you cannot use this intention in the desired way. I think, you should generate those fields. You can try using "Replace Structurally" Idea's tool, regexps or something else.

For info on using Replace Structurally see [JetBrains Tutorial](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/ssr.html)